# WPF WriteableBitmap to byte array

Tags: c#, wpf, writeablebitmap

Is there anyway to convert a WriteableBitmap to byte array? I assign the writeablebitmap to an System.Windows.Controls.Image source too if there's a way to get it from that. I tried this but got a  general GDI exception on FromHBitmap.

```
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(wb.BackBuffer);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
myarray = ms.ToArray();
```

Comment: where is the WriteableBitmap in your code?

Comment: Declared in the class scope, but I edited it to make more sense.

Comment: now that you changed Data to BackBuffer it makes more sense

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code encodes the image data in PNG format, but `FromHBitmap` expects raw, unencoded bitmap data.

Try this:

```
var width = bitmapSource.PixelWidth;
var height = bitmapSource.PixelHeight;
var stride = width * ((bitmapSource.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8);

var bitmapData = new byte[height * stride];

bitmapSource.CopyPixels(bitmapData, stride, 0);
```

...where `bitmapSource` is your `WriteableBitmap` (or any other `BitmapSource`).

Comment: There is no .Format.BitsPerPixel on an WriteableBitmap object in UWP. Also, CopyPixels doesn't exist. Why there are so big differences between the same data types in WPF and UWP?